# this.props.relay.setVariables() doesnt fetch new results (but change variable as well)

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relay

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, but I can't make work refetching new range via change variable.

Here is part of my relay container code (on initial it works well and fetch first 5 results):

```
export const Account = Relay.createContainer(_Account, {
  initialVariables: {
    activities: 5
  },

  fragments: {
    account: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on NodeInterface {
        id
        ... on Member {
          activities(first: $activities) {
            totalCount
            edges {
              node {
                id
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
  },
});
```

Here is part of React component what changes relay variable:

```
export class _Account extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activities: 5
    };
  }

  loadMoreActivities(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState((state,props) => {
      const next = state.activities + 5;
      this.props.relay.setVariables({
        activities: next
      });
      return { activities: next }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>

                <div>{ this.state.activities.toString() } - { this.props.relay.variables.activities.toString() }</div>
                <ProfileActivityList 
                 activities={this.props.account.activities} 
                 loadMore={this.loadMoreActivities.bind(this)} />
                }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure out what is wrong. `pageInfo` data is important to pagination. I just add `pageInfo` to query and everything works as excepted.